# Importing XML into Premiere Pro - numbered stills / image sequence

Tags: premiere, automation, xml

I'm trying to make life a bit easier by generating an XML file to quickly import a number of image sequences into a Premiere Pro project (PPro 2017.0.2 in case it matters).

It almost works - but when I import this XML file into premiere, it imports the first file in the sequence as a Still Image rather than an image sequence.
The path to the file is correct, and the first frame does show up just fine.

It feels like it's only a small change that's required, but I have not been able to find any information on it anywhere.

Since the (sample) XML is very short, I also included it here (the real file has a few hundred clips, they all behave the same way).

I tried manually importing an image sequence into premiere and exporting the result as FinalCut XML, but if I re-import that file, it also gets imported as a Still Image, so no help there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xmeml version="4">  
  <bin>  
    <name>mpf_07 Images</name>  
    <children>  
      <bin>  
        <name>Preview</name>  
        <children>  
          <clip id="mpf_07_01">  
            <duration>229</duration>  
            <in>0</in>  
            <out>229</out>  
            <name>mpf_07_01</name>  
            <media>  
              <video>  
                <track>  
                  <clipitem id="clipitem-Preview-mpf_07_01">  
                    <name>clipitem-Preview-mpf_07_01</name>  
                    <file id="file-Preview-mpf_07_01">  
                      <name />  
                      <pathurl>E:\mpf_07_01.0101.jpg</pathurl>  
                      <rate>  
                        <timebase>24</timebase>  
                        <NTSC>FALSE</NTSC>  
                      </rate>  
                      <duration>320</duration>  
                      <timecode>  
                        <rate>  
                          <timebase>24</timebase>  
                          <ntsc>FALSE</ntsc>  
                        </rate>  
                        <string>00:00:00:00</string>  
                        <frame>0</frame>  
                        <displayformat>NDF</displayformat>  
                        <reel>  
                          <name />  
                        </reel>  
                      </timecode>  
                      <media>  
                        <video>  
                          <samplecharacteristics>  
                            <width>2048</width>  
                            <height>1126</height>  
                          </samplecharacteristics>  
                        </video>  
                      </media>  
                    </file>  
                  </clipitem>  
                </track>  
              </video>  
            </media>  
            <rate>  
              <timebase>24</timebase>  
              <NTSC>FALSE</NTSC>  
            </rate>  
          </clip>  
        </children>  
      </bin>  
    </children>  
  </bin>  
</xmeml>
```

To clarify, this is the setting when using the Premiere UI to set it up, everything else works except Premiere doesn't see the Bin as an image sequence, but rather as a still image:
[image: To clarify, this is the setting when using the Premiere UI to set it up]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that this is not possible - at least as per the time of writing this answer, since the concept of "image sequence" does not exist in the XML spec Premiere utilizes - namely, XMEML version 4, also known as Final Cut Pro 7-style XML.